# JavaScript p5: TypeError: pos is undefined

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Here is my code, it is supposed to be able to render a canvas with a snake and its food and whenever the snake is within 1 pixel of it, the food moves to a new location.
As I have said in the title the error reads/; TypeError: pos is undefined

```
var snake;
var scl = 10;
var food;

function setup()
{
  //Sets the Canvas
  createCanvas(700, 700);

  //Creates a new object using the variable snake
  snake = new Snake();

  //Sets the frame rate
  frameRate(10);

  //Creates a vector called food
  //setLocation();
}

function draw()
{
  //Sets the Background, number implies the colour
  background(50);

  //Adds all the values set within the function to the snake
  snake.updateSnake();
  snake.showSnake();
  snake.keyPressed();

  if(snake.eatFood(food))
  {
    food.updateFood();
  }

  food.showFood();
  food.updateFood();
}
  /*Here we setup the food
  //fill(255, 0, 10);
  rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);

}


function setLocation()
//{
  //var columns = floor(width/scl);
  //var rows = floor(height/scl);

  //food = createVector(floor(random(columns)), floor(random(rows)));
  //food.mult(scl);
*/

function Food()
{
  this.showFood = function()
  {
    fill(255, 0, 10);
    rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);
  }

  this.updateFood = function()
  {
    var columns = floor(width/scl);
    var rows = floor(height/scl);

    food = createVector(floor(random(columns)), floor(random(rows)));
    food.mult(scl);
  }
}


function Snake()
{
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.xspeed = 0;
  this.yspeed = 0;

  this.updateSnake = function()
  {
    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;

    this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - scl);
    this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - scl);
  }

  this.showSnake = function()
  {
    fill(255);
    rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
  }

  this.direction = function(x, y)
  {
    this.xspeed = x;
    this.yspeed = y;
  }

  this.eatFood = function(pos)
  {
    var distance = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);

    if(distance < 1)
    {
      return true;

      console.log("WITHIN RANGE");

    }else
    {
      return false;

      console.log("OUTSIDE RANGE");

    }
  }

  this.keyPressed = function()
  {
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW)
    {
      snake.direction(0, -1);
    } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW)
    {
      snake.direction(0, 1);
    } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW)
    {
      snake.direction(1, 0);
    } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW)
    {
      snake.direction(-1, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure Snake is a function? For me it should be a class.

Comment: To be honest, I have no Idea.

Answer (score 1):

I see you created the food variable, but I can't see where you actually initialize it. food is undefined, but you then pass it to the eatFood method, which gives you an error.

Try putting this in your setup function.

```
food = new Food()
```

Then you need to give it an initial x and y value. Perhaps using Math.random()

**EDIT**
You may need to rethink parts of your code.

Firstly, make the columns and rows a global variable or at least scoped to the Food class.

```
var snake;
var scl = 10;
var food;
var columns = floor(width/scl);
var rows = floor(height/scl);
```

You should call updateFood as soon as the Food is created. So put it in the constructor or call it immediately after creating food. Just make sure it comes after the this.updateFood method. Example:

```
function Food()
{
    this.updateFood = ... // blah blah code here
    ...
    this.updateFood();
}
```

To avoid writing over your food object, make sure you're setting that vector to something scoped to food. Such as a position.

```
this.updateFood = function()
{
    this.pos = createVector(floor(random(columns)), floor(random(rows)));
    this.pos.mult(scl);
}
```

Lastly, when the snake eats the food, make sure you're passing the food object and then grab it's position. (Unless you decide to give food a this.x and this.y field).

```
this.eatFood = function(food)
{
    var distance = dist(this.x, this.y, food.pos.x, food.pos.y);
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you can have multiple food items on the screen at once if you decide to.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use Math.random() as i'm confused? Also  i added the code you gave me but the new error I get now reads TypeError: food.showFood is not a function.

Comment: Math.random is a javascript function, but you're using p5, which already has a random function that it seems you know how to use that does something comparable. If you want to read more about Math.random you can google it easily enough.

Upon reading your code some more I see that in your update food method you're resetting the food variable. My suggestion is in the constructor for Food you should set the position, then in the updateFood method, you update that position.

Comment: This is what I added to set the location in function Food():                      
  this.x = random(this.x);
  this.y = random(this.y);                                                                                                     I also don't understand what you mean by updating the postion in updateFood, wasn't I already doing that. Sorry if my questions are a bit noobish as I'm quite low level in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialise food. You only declare the variable. You need to do: `food = new Food();` somewhere in the program. Best to put it in the setup method. It also won't work because the Food function does not have a `this.x` and `this.y`.

Answer (score 0):

It's calling the `draw()` function before `food` has been set. `food` is your pos variable, so it's crashing there. Make sure you initialize food to something before calling

```
if(snake.eatFood(food)){
    food.updateFood();
}
```